# protractor fails to detect a redirect in IE

Tags: protractor

I have a fairly simple test for our AngularJS application, which basically checks whether the application is properly redirecting to the dashboard page when the root URL "/" is loaded. This test works well in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) but fails in IE 10/11. This is how the test looks:

```
it('should redirect to the dashboard', function () {
    browser.get('/');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('#/dashboard');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Dashboard');
});
```

I did follow the instructions in the browser setup section of the protractor docs, and I'm running the multi-browser protractor tests using grunt. All the other tests pass in IE as well as the other browsers. It feels like I must be doing something stupid here?

I have tried to use a delay right after the `browser.get('/')` call, and I could see the IE (while the test was running) actually being redirected, but only after the delay, so the test still failed.

I'm still quite new to both AngularJS and protractor, so any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i think it will useful to you.

```
 browser.getLocationAbsUrl().then(function(url) {
        expect(url.split('#')[1]).toBe('/dashboard');
          expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('dashboard');
    });
```